# Updating urlpatterns for django-smart-selects

Tags: django

I am attempting *my first django project* by building on top of the polls example from the django documentation.

I would like to add linked/cascading dropdowns to a form and found my way to django-smart-selects.

I read [the documentation](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) but wasn't sure how to integrate the suggested updates to project's urls.py urlpatterns from the documentation into what I have currently.

The smart select urls mentioned in the linked documentation

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
)
```

The current value of urlpatterns in my project's ursl.py file.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('TimeTracking.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('data-browser/', include('data_browser.urls')),
]
```

Obviously adding those entries to my urlpatterns = [] wouldn't work but I attemtped it anyway...

> NameError: name 'url' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
urlpatterns = [
            path('', include('TimeTracking.urls')),
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
            re_path(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
            path('data-browser/', include('data_browser.urls')),
        ]
```